# How can one estimate the cost of a website like this?

Tags: freelance-websites

I want to calculate the Cost of developing the website exactly like this one: www.mazumamobile.com Can somebody guide me as how they have integrated this imei mobile search plugin and how much does it cost to buy it?

Comment: It would cost quite a bit. This is a significant website, with lots of data and tons of great functionality. It has matured and developed and is a significant website that has been extremely well built. Impossible to say what else it does on the backend, or the contracts it uses, or the security checks it runs. You could make a mockery of it and impersonate it poorly. Otherwise you are talking about a very significant investment, at a minimum of £20k but probably a lot more. That does not include the marketing, brand awareness, advertising or PR costs. This is in fact a silly question to ask I

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the cost of the website, first you need to generate a functional requirements document comprising **every** feature on this site.  Don't leave anything out, and don't write the functional requirements to be specific to any software platform.

You should CHARGE for the work done to create this complex functional requirements document.  If the client won't pay for this deliverable, don't take the job.  The end result is actually something the client can use, whether you end up doing the work or not.

After that's done, decide on a platform.

Then, for each feature that you've put out there in the functional requirement, do an estimate on how many hours it'll take for you to build that feature.  Be sure to allocate time for testing and any research needed.

Decide on your hourly rate (how much money you'd like to "take home"), and multiply that by the sum of the hours.  For sake of your sanity, add another 30% to that number.

When you turn your numbers over to the client, be sure that you have grouped major features into "milestones" and that you're getting paid for each milestone completed instead of collecting all the money at the end (unless the client is paying up-front).  The reasons are numerous - look up "milestone" on this site to understand more.